# How to export Substrate native interface to runtime?

Tags: substrate

I'm trying link the substrate tutorial (https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) to some C library. I wrapped the C library to a crate called `cfun`, which can called by the node layer.

I figured out I can use the marco `runtime_interface` to export the native interface for my pallets to call. However, although I can compile successfully, the wasm runtime cannot instantiate.

**Any idea what is happening?**

```rust
// node/cfun/src/lib.rs
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

#[link(name = "test", kind = "static")]
extern "C" {
    pub fn double_int(input: i32) -> i32;
    pub fn double_uint(input: u32) -> u32;
}
```

```sh
# node/cint/Cargo.toml
[package]
edition = '2018'
name = 'cint'
version = '2.0.1'

[dependencies]
# local dependencies
sp-runtime-interface = { version = "2.0.1", default-features = false}
cfun = { path = '../cfun', default-features = false, version = '2.0.1', optional = true }

[features]
default = ['std']
std = [
    'sp-runtime-interface/std',
    'cfun',
]
```

```rust
// node/cint/src/lib.rs
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

#[cfg(feature = "std")]
extern crate cfun;

use sp_runtime_interface::runtime_interface;

#[runtime_interface]
pub trait CFunctions {
    fn c_double_uint(input: u32) -> u32 {
        unsafe {
            cfun::double_uint(input)
        }
    }
}
```

```rust
// pallets/template/src/lib.rs

// import module at the beginning
extern crate cint;

// ...
// modify the original `do_something` function
// from:
// Something::put(something);
// to:
let smt = cint::c_functions::c_double_uint(something);
Something::put(smt);
```

[image: runtime error]

**Edited 1**

```sh
# pallets/template.Cargo.toml and runtime/Cargo.toml
# path is a bit different, but both included all interfaces

[dependencies]
# ...
sp-runtime-interface = { version = "2.0.1", default-features = false}
cfun = { path = '../../node/cfun', default-features = false, version = '2.0.1', optional = true }
cint = { path = '../../node/cint', default-features = false, version = '2.0.1'}

[features]
default = ['std']
std = [
    # ...
    'sp-runtime/std',
    'cfun',
    'cint/std',
]
```

Repo:
https://github.com/killalau/substrate-node-template/tree/franky

Comment: Aside from your current issue, even if that is solved, `Something::put(smt);` makes we want to shout that if `smt` is not `Encode`, you can't put it in storage.

Comment: @kianenigma How to perform the `Encode`? Like this? `Something::put(frame_support::codec::Encode(smt))`

Comment: No, the type of the value you pass needs to implement `Encode`. Your code is fine because `Encode` is implemented for `u32`.

Comment: Did you make sure to also provide the interface? Like, the runtime is started with an environment that needs to include your interface.

Comment: @apopiak I've edited the content above, I think I'd included the interface.

Comment: FYI, I've added my repo in description